# How to interpret the standard error for a factor regression?

Tags: r, regression, standard-deviation, standard-error

I would like to know how to interpret the coefficient standard errors of a factor regression when using the display function in R. I have a data set which has three variables: winner of 2016 elections, a signal dummy variable and a change in spending (in percentage points).

I am getting the following output which I would like to graph.

```
 winner2016      income_quartile term                         estimate std.error statistic       p.value
   <pseries>       <pseries>       <chr>                           <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl>
 1 Donald Trump    1               (Intercept)                     4.10      0.811     5.06  0.000000749  
 2 Donald Trump    1               factor(signalReopening2to1)1   -2.18      1.53     -1.42  0.155
```

How would I get the error bars for Trump with a "good signal"? I know that for Donald Trump without signal I would use the std. error times 1.96, but I am unsure how to do it with the standard error for the factor variable. Should I add the two standard errors?

Thank you for help.